# Graph theory - inequality

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm having troubles solving the following problem which is about proving an inequality in the field of graph theory.

We consider `G = (V,E)` a graph with n a natural number (n is the number of vertices), that doesn't contain any triangles. (so the vertices don't form any triangle inside the graph)

the problem is about solving :   |E|≤ (n^2) / 4

all I know is that `{u,v}∈E : deg(u)+deg(v) ≤ n`
(I don't know if it is relevant to the problem though...)

Comment: What does $n$ have to do with the graph?

Comment: n is the number of Vertices, I'll edit my post

Comment: If we write it for all edges, we get
$$\sum_{u\in V} deg(u)^2\ \le\ |E|\cdot n$$
However, I'm not sure if it is the right direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that if $\vec a, \vec b \in \mathbb R^n$, then $\vec a \cdot \vec b \leq \|\vec a\|  \|\vec b\|$, which can be rewritten as:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i \right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2 \right)
$$
Now let $V = \{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ and take $a_i = 1$ and $b_i = \deg v_i$.
Then it follows that:
\begin{align*}
|E|
&= \frac{(2|E|)^2}{4|E|} \\
&= \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1\deg v_i \right)^2}{4|E|} &\text{by the handshaking lemma}\\
&\leq \frac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n 1^2 \right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (\deg v_i)^2 \right)}{4|E|} &\text{by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality}\\
&= \frac{n\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{v_iv_j \in E} (\deg v_i) }{4|E|} \\
&= \frac{n\sum_{v_iv_j \in E} (\deg v_i + \deg v_j)}{4|E|} \\
&\leq \frac{n(n|E|)}{4|E|} &\text{since $G$ is triangle-free}\\
&= \frac{n^2}{4}
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

Let $v$ be a vertex of maximum degree in $G=(V,E)$.  Then $$\mathrm{deg}(v) \geq \text{ave. deg.} = \dfrac{2|E|}{n} \geq \dfrac{n}{2}$$ since $|E| \leq n^2/4$.

Let $S$ be the set of neighbors of $v$.  Let $H$ be the complete bipartite graph with vertex bipartition formed by $S$ and $V \setminus S$.

We observe:

- $H$ has at most $n^2/4$ edges,
- in going from $G$ to $H$,

  - the degree of $v$ remains the same,
  - the degrees of the vertices in $S$ are no smaller in $H$ than in $G$, and
  - the degrees of the vertices in $V \setminus ( S \cup \{v\} )$ are now all equal to $|S|=\mathrm{deg}(v)$, which is the maximum degree in $G$,

  so $H$ has no fewer edges than $G$, and
- $H$ is triangle free.

Hence $|E| \leq n^2/4$.